# When pressing back on a dialogfragment, how do I close its containing activity?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have a splash screen Activity that shows a custom DialogFragment.  When I press back, I want to close not only the dialogfragment but it's containing activity.

The DialogFragment lacks a onBackPressed(), otherwise I would put

```
getActivity().finish()
```

in that callback.  I also don't want to put that in onDetach() because if the user clicks on an element in the dialogfragment, it should populate a listview in that same splash activity instead of closing the app.

Comment: What holds you from processing onBackPressed() in your Activity?

Comment: If I add finish() in there it has no effect whatsoever, I hit back, the dialogfragment closes and I see a loading splash screen when I don't want to(because it tells the user something is loading when it isn't).

Answer (score 5):

Why use `onDismiss` callback? Like this:

```
@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
    getActivity().finish();
}
```

Or Override the `onBackPressed` in your activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    MyFragment myFrag = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("myFrag");
    if (myFrag != null && myFrag.mDialog.isShowing())
        myFrag.mDialog.dismiss();
        finish();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: If I click on something in the dialogfragment I don't want the app to close.  This has the same effect as my onDetach() solution.  I only want to close everything if I hit the BACK button from my dialogfragment

Comment: @HukeLau_DABA update my answer with an example onBackPressed which is your only hope it seems.

Comment: there wasn't a difference between having that onBackPressed override and not having it.  I press back, still see the splash screen.  Pressing back again closes the splash.  I want to close the splash from the dialog when pressing back only, not anytime the dialog closes, like if I select something in that dialog

Comment: @HukeLau_DABA I don't see what's preventing you from closing the splash inside the onBackPressed, before finishing your activity. Also it sounds like a bad design, having some kind of splash and a dialog open at the same time.

Comment: your code is preventing me from closing the splash; it still requires 2 back presses.

Comment: @HukeLau_DABA Please be more specific than "splash". That can be anything.

Comment: activity A is my "splash" screen.  It says "loading" until an api call succeeds and fills my dialogfragment with a listview.  If I click on a row in that listview the dialog closes and populates a listview in activity A after it hides the loading message.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ShadowDialog extends DialogFragment {
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.shadow_loader,null);

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity()){
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            super.onBackPressed();
            getActivity().onBackPressed();
        }
    };
    dialog.setContentView(view);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    return dialog;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could try overriding onKeyDown() to detect Back button press in your DialogFragment:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        ....
```

Comment: if the dialogfragment is visible and you press back, onKeyDown or onBackPressed in the activity is actually not invoked.  They are invoked after the dialogfragment has been destroyed and you press back again, when only the splash screen is available.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       Dialog dialog = new Dialog(requireContext()){
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            super.onBackPressed();
            requireActivity().finish();
           // or requireActivity().onBackPressed();
        }
       };
    return dialog;
     }
```